# SQLite: Workaround for SQLite-TRIGGER with WITH

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers, with-statement

I'm working on a project to monitor downtimes of production lines with an embedded device. I want to automate acknowledging of these downtimes by generic rules the user can configure.
I want to use a TRIGGER but get a syntax error near UPDATE even though the documentation says it should be fine to use the WITH statement.

```
CREATE TRIGGER autoAcknowledge
    AFTER UPDATE OF dtEnd ON ackGroups
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN old.dtEnd IS NULL AND new.dtEnd IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        WITH sub1(id, stationId, groupDur) AS (
            SELECT MIN(d.id), d.station,
                strftime('%s', ag.dtEnd) - strftime('%s', ag.dtStart) 
                FROM ackGroups AS ag
                LEFT JOIN downtimes AS d on d.acknowledge = ag.id
                WHERE ag.id = old.id
                GROUP BY ag.id ),
            sub2( originId, groupDur, reasonId, above, ruleDur) AS (
                SELECT sub1.stationId, sub1.groupDur, aar.reasonId, aar.above, aar.duration
                FROM sub1
                LEFT JOIN autoAckStations AS aas ON aas.stationId = sub1.stationId
                LEFT JOIN autoAckRules AS aar ON aas.autoAckRuleId = aar.id
                ORDER BY duration DESC )
        UPDATE ackGroups SET (reason, dtAck, origin)=(
            SELECT reasonId, datetime('now'), originId
            FROM sub2 as s
            WHERE ( s.ruleDur < s.groupDur AND above = 1 ) OR (s.ruleDur > s.groupDur AND above = 0)
            LIMIT 1
        )
        WHERE id = old.id;
    END
```

Background: First we have the downtimes table. Each production line consists of multiple parts called stations. Each station can start the line downtime and they can overlap with other stations downtimes.

```
CREATE TABLE "downtimes" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    "station" integer NOT NULL, 
    "acknowledge" integer, 
    "dtStart" datetime NOT NULL, 
    "dtEnd" datetime, 
    "dtLastModified" datetime)
```

Overlaping downtimes are grouped to acknowledge groups using TRIGGER AFTER INSERT on downtimes to set acknowledge id right or create a new group.

```
CREATE TABLE "ackGroups" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    "reason" integer, 
    "dtAck" datetime, 
    "dtStart" datetime NOT NULL, 
    "dtEnd" datetime, 
    "line" integer NOT NULL, 
    "origin" integer)
```

The autoAckRules table represents the configuration. The user decides whether the rule should apply to durations higher or lower a certain value and which rasonId should be used to acknowledge.

```
CREATE TABLE "autoAckRules" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    "description" text NOT NULL, 
    "reasonId" integer NOT NULL, 
    "above" bool NOT NULL, 
    "duration" real NOT NULL)
```

The autoAckStations table is used to manage M:N relationship. Each rule allow multiple stations which started the ackGroup.

```
CREATE TABLE autoAckStations (
        autoAckRuleId INTEGER NOT NULL,
        stationId INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY ( autoAckRuleId, stationId )
    )
```

When the last downtime ends `dtEnd` of `ackGroups` is set to `datetime('now')` and the trigger is fired to check if there is a autoAckRule that fits.

If I substitute the sub selects with a `SELECT .. FROM( SELECT .. FROM(SELECT .. FROM )))` cascade
is there a nice way to avoid the need to write and evaluate it twice?

Or am I missing something stupid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common table expression are not supported for statements inside of [triggers](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html). You need to convert CTE to sub-query such as

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER autoAcknowledge
AFTER UPDATE OF dtEnd ON ackGroups
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN old.dtEnd IS NULL AND new.dtEnd IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE ackGroups 
       SET (reason, dtAck, origin)= (
    SELECT reasonId, datetime('now'), originId
      FROM (SELECT sub1.stationId AS originId,
                   sub1.groupDur  AS groupDur, 
                   aar.reasonId   AS reasonId, 
                   aar.above      AS above, 
                   aar.duration   AS ruleDur
             FROM (SELECT MIN(d.id) AS id,
                         d.station AS stationId,
                         strftime('%s', ag.dtEnd) - strftime('%s', ag.dtStart) AS groupDur 
                    FROM ackGroups AS ag
                    LEFT 
                    JOIN downtimes AS d 
                      ON d.acknowledge = ag.id
                   WHERE ag.id = old.id
                   GROUP BY ag.id ) AS sub1
            LEFT 
            JOIN autoAckStations AS aas 
              ON aas.stationId = sub1.stationId
            LEFT 
            JOIN autoAckRules AS aar 
              ON aas.autoAckRuleId = aar.id
           ORDER BY duration DESC) as s
        WHERE ( s.ruleDur < s.groupDur AND above = 1 ) OR (s.ruleDur > s.groupDur AND above = 0)
        LIMIT 1
    );
END;
```

Comment: without common table expressions WITH is useless :(   but nice formatting